# Is this the right way to raw query? - Android

Tags: android, sql

I just want to ask if this is the correct way to use select,from etc and if my conditions are right:

```
private Cursor delete(){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();
        String mySQL = " select"+ _ID+ "from " + TABLE_NAME + "where" + _ID + "==" + deleteAnAppointment.getText().toString();
        Cursor idToDelete = db.rawQuery(mySQL, null);
        startManagingCursor(idToDelete);
        return idToDelete;
    }

    private void selectToDelete(Cursor cursor){
        calendarData = new CalendarData(this);
        SQLiteDatabase db = calendarData.getWritableDatabase();
        if(cursor.getCount() > 0){
            db.delete(TABLE_NAME, _ID+" = "+deleteAnAppointment.getText().toString(), null);
        }

    }
```

I'm not getting any result anyway but just want to see if its the correct way to format the SQL, thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nope, your query is faulty.

Change this:

```
String mySQL = " select"+ _ID+ "from " + TABLE_NAME + "where" + _ID + "==" +
      deleteAnAppointment.getText().toString();
Cursor idToDelete = db.rawQuery(mySQL, null);
```

To this:

```
String mySQL = "SELECT "+ _ID+ " FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE " + _ID + " = ?";
Cursor idToDelete = db.rawQuery(mySQL, 
     new String[]{deleteAnAppointment.getText().toString()});
```

Comment: it allows android to take care of inserting string values in query. because your string parameters are supposed to be encapsulated with in single quotes like `'value'`. So **?** mark is a placeholder which is translated as `'deleteAnAppointment.getText().toString()'`